# How to group categorical values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, categorical-data

I'm trying Converting to categorical value and grouping in pandas.

For example, I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = ['C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3']
df['B'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

df['A'] = df.loc[:,'A'].astype('category')

df2 = df[0:3]

result = df2.groupby(by='A')['B'].nunique()

print(result)
```

Unfortunately, I get the exception

> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 86, in **init**
> len(self.values), len(self.mgr_locs)))
>
> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 3

**Edit**
Unfortunately, the workaround suggested by @joris does not work for my application. New counterexample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = ['C1', 'C1', 'C2', pd.np.nan, 'C3', 'C3']
df['B'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

df['A'] = df.loc[:,'A'].astype('category')

df2 = df[0:4]

df2['A'] = df2['A'].cat.remove_unused_categories()

result = df2.groupby(by='A')['B'].nunique()

print(result)
```

Comment: I tried it works fine me what version of pandas you are using?

Comment: Pandas 17.0. What version are you using?

Comment: Have the same error with pandas 0.17.0 ... the error occurs when calling `nunique()`

Comment: Mine is `Out[11]: '0.16.2'` and works fine

Comment: same error with Pandas 17.0 and python 3.5

Comment: This seems a regression in pandas 0.17.0, reported it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11635

Comment: @SpiderOtto As a workaround, you can first do ``df2['A'] = df2['A'].cat.remove_unused_categories()` before grouping

Comment: You are hitting another bug ... one with `remove_unused_categories` when having `NaN` values, see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11599. But for this, you can always do first a `dropna`

Comment: Try this `result = df2.groupby(by='A')['B'].unique().map(lambda x: len(x))`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a regression in pandas 0.17.0, and reported here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11635

As a workaround for now, you can easily use the `nunique` Series method through `apply` instead of calling it directly on the groupby object:

```
In [22]: df2.groupby(by='A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
Out[22]:
A
C1    2
C2    1
C3    0
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

The other problem you encountered with `remove_unused_categories()` is also a bug, and this will be fixed in 0.17.1 (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11639)